# Weird issue with Video card

Tags: graphics-card

I have set up a new computer which has on board video and an NVidia GT740. In the bios it is set to default to PCI Express for video and windows show the video card installed being the GT740. All the GT740 utilities work and show the CPU usage of the card in real time. Basically everything is working perfectly expect that I am plugged into the on board HDMI port. Is this a feature where the VGA card takes control of the on board ports?? If I plug into the HDMI on the card then it works but is the boot up is not reliable, it often defaults to the on board HDMI port. Are there any settings to change this?

Comment: The default video device is usually set in the BIOS.

Comment: I did say it was a weird problem. What I am saying is that all indicators show the PCI express video card (GT740) is working except that the only way to get video is to plug into the on board video. Device manager does not show the on board video as being a device at all yet I have to plug into the motherboard's HDMI port to get anything to show on the screen. If I plug into the gt740's HDMI port I get nothing.

Comment: It's looks quite clear to me. The computer has a PCI Express video card, the drivers for it are installed but the only way to get video is to plug into the on board video. The drivers for the onboard video are not installed, not there and do not show up. The onboard video is not in device manager at all. It is as if the PCI express card is taking control of the onboard video port. Is this possible?

Comment: " If I plug into the HDMI on the card then it works but is the boot up is not reliable"  This is clear? we are reading trying to understand and get clues from how it is operating, but still cant tell what you see at Post, which should show bios on either screen. Then what really does this mean? does it even boot up ok "not reliable" ?  You still have not stated the motherboard being used?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it. ALL indicator are that the PCI express card is the working card, the drivers are installed etc. Windows tells me the monitor is plugged into the PCI express card. ALL indicators are the motherboard video card is not active, no drivers installed, it is not working, not there, not doing anything, not showing in device manager. It all looks good. BUT the monitor is plugged into the onboard port.

Comment: If I plug into the PCI express card then sometimes it boots up with video but sometimes not. If not then I need to shift the cable to the onboard port.

Comment: Do you understand? All indicators are that the PCI express card is running the video but the only way to get video is to plug into the onboard port. It's very odd.